# Jquery mobile error when going back

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm getting this error when clicking the back button to go back a page in jQuery mobile to a search listing page. Note, everything after #job-results? is built dynamically based on form selections on a previous page.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #job-results?WorkTypes=Fixed%20Term&Locations=Brisbane
```

This is the code of the search results block

```
<!-- Results Page -->
<div id="job-results" data-role="page">

    <div class="lcpl-header" data-id="header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="back" data-icon="search">Search</a>
        <h1>Job search</h1>
        <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/?home" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="home">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div id="job-search-results" data-role="content">
        <h2 id="job-search-results-title"></h2>
        <div id="job-search-results-wrap" class="listings">
            <div class="loading"><div class="loading-icon"></div>Loading results</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php include 'footer-bar.php'; ?>

</div><!-- /page -->
```

#### Versions

jQuery 1.8.3
jQuery Mobile JS 1.2.1 
jQuery Mobile CSS 1.2.1

Comment: Where do you use that URL? Maybe `Syntax error, unrecognized expression` is being thrown because of the lack of quotes (`"`) for the URL string somewhere?

Comment: Step 1. A form to select job types. `site.com/job-search Step 2`. A job results page that loads the result. `site.com/job-search/#job-results?WorkTypes=Permanent%20Full-time` (or something similar) Then Step 3. Loads the job detail page `site.com/job-search/#job-detail?job=972874%2Fpeople-capability-administrator` (or something similar)

So clicking the back button should just use the browser history to go to step 2.

Comment: Weird... Can you post some code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Do you mean the Browsers "back" button or another button on your page? Due to the AJAX nature of JQM, the navigation of pages can be fowled when a users clicks the browsers back button.